# Make multiple embedded div's height the same with their parent div's height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I have this html structure:

```
<div id="loggedin" class="container-fluid">      
    <div class="row-fluid">    
        <div class="span2">
            <div id="navigation">
                <div id="opacnav">
                    <div class="well">                         
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="opacnavbottom">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="span7">  
            <div id="opacmainuserblock">
                <div class="well">                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="span3">             
            <div id="opacnavright">               
            </div>                
        </div>      
    </div> 
</div>
```

I want div's with class row-fluid, span2, navigation, and div's with an id of opacnav and class well be of the same height with their parent div with id loggedin. How will I do that?

Heres's my initial css code:

```
#loggedin > .row-fluid{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}

#loggedin > .row-fluid > .span2{   
    align-items: stretch;   
    width: 23.076923076923077%;
    background: green;   
}

#loggedin > .row-fluid > .span2 > #navigation {      
    align-items: stretch;  
    background: blue;
}

#loggedin > .row-fluid > .span2 > #navigation > #opacnav{   
    align-items: stretch;  
    background: red;
}

#loggedin > .row-fluid > .span2 > #navigation > #opacnav > .well{   
    align-items: stretch;  
    background: yellow;
}

#loggedin > .row-fluid > .span7{
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 48.5%;
    background: orange;
}

#loggedin > .row-fluid > .span3{
    align-items: stretch;    
    background: pink;
}
```

The yellow, orange and pink color should populate the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the child divs to inherit the height of the parent div.  This can be done by giving the parent div of #loggedin a height and then setting height to inherit for all of the child divs.  So you would add this to parent div (using 600px and red as examples):

```
#loggedin {
height:600px;
background-color:red;
}
```

and then on the children:

```
.child-element {
  height:inherit;
 }
```

Providing an updated fiddle to show all colors.  Some were missing widths which is why they weren't showing.  These widths are just samples:

http://jsfiddle.net/opr57w4b/3/

Comment: I tried to do it but it does'nt work. The yellow orange and pink should populate on the screen.

Comment: It looks like some of the divs that aren't showing don't have widths.  I added height:inherit and width:inherit to those: http://jsfiddle.net/opr57w4b/1/

Comment: @Maitar--> thanks, but the color yellow, orange and pink must only populate the screen, not all of them. Maybe it still needs to be tweak a bit. :)

Comment: --> tHanks for giving me an idea.